# React material UI accordion: how to call a function when accordion is open?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using React material-ui.
I'm trying to call a function only when the `Accordion` is open:

```
                                <Accordion  opened={()=>this.myFn(row.id)} >
                                <AccordionSummary

                                    expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon/>}
                                    aria-controls="panel1a-content"
                                    id={row.id}

                                >
                                    <Typography>{row.name}</Typography>
                                </AccordionSummary>
                                <AccordionDetails id={row.id} >

                                   <p>something <p/>

                                </AccordionDetails>
                            </Accordion>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is props in `Accordian` `onChange` you can pass it and track it if accordian is open fire this function i.e

```
<Accordion onChange = {(e,expanded) => {
        if(expanded){
          calledFunction()
        }
      }}>
```

In your case it would be something like this:

```
<Accordion   onChange = {(e,expanded) => {
        if(expanded){
          this.myFn(row.id)
        }
      }} >
```

Here is demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/spring-leftpad-uu9yc?file=/demo.js